# Speeding up web applications with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jsf

In a particular web application that I am working on, it needs to load a lot of data for a webpage. The page has 4 main sections. When a user goes to this page it needs to have all 4 sections populated.

If I load each section sequentially then this is going to take awhile to load up the entire page. There are a lot of queries that will need to run to get the data. I was wondering if using threads for each section in the backing bean (UI bean) is a good idea here (essentially calling each method in the service bean in a thread). I know spawning off threads in a web application is usually considered risky. So I am looking for advices.

Some background info: the application is being developed in JSF 1.2 with weblogic as the container.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is, it depends.

If all sections just query from same db its pointless.
If you do some serious heavy calculations on something than you can consider threading.